How to configure position/z-order of a Qt application in a Wayland compositor?
I developed a Qt program (QGuiApplication, 5.12) on Ubuntu Linux.
Another person provides a Wayland compositor (I don't know its technique details).
Now, I can successfully start my program in that Wayland compositor by the following command.
./my_program -platform=wayland

The Wayland compositor's resolution is 1920x800 and my program's resolution is 1280x720.
After my program started, I can see it is put in the left-top corner.
Question 1:
How to put it in the right-top corner? Can I specify a (x,y) coordinate as the left-top point to my program?
Question 2:
Assume that another program will run in this Wayland compositor, too. I would like to let my program displayed under other programs.
Is there a way to dynamically adjust the z-order of my program?
Thank you.
